# css alternative to javascript positioning

Tags: css

I have the following javascript that I am using to position an element when some other event happens:

```
$('div.arrow').css('top', @$().offset().top - 20)
```

The above works but I am curious as to whether it is possible to get the same effect using pure css?

I only need to worry about modern browsers so no worries about legacy IE problems.

Comment: Is that SASS/LESS? What is the `@$()` representing in the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty compatible:

```
div.arrow {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

If there's already a `position` attribute on `div.arrow`, you won't need to specify it again, unless it's `position: static`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the action in particular that you want to cause this change?

The only way to effectively "action" a CSS change is the checkbox hack - but if you're looking to simply change the position of an element when something is clicked (for example) you could have the click event give a class of "active" to the element in question.

For example;

```
div.arrow { regular: styles here; }
div.arrow.active { 
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

To be honest though, your way is probably the most efficient already, especially if it's an onClick event.